# Retrofitting an old compressor with VFD

Tags: motors, compressors

For an AC unit, the compressor - GK151PAB - Hermetic type, Permanent split condenser,2 pole, Single phase, Induction motor. This much I know about it. What else do I need to know and how do I find out those things in order to asses feasibility of VFD-ing my compressor ?

Comment: I think it's a bit unusual to try to run a capacitor-start motor off a VFD so you may be interested in this: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/235212/can-you-use-a-vfd-to-run-a-capacitor-start-motor

Comment: @DKNguyen Thanks! I wonder if "Permanent split condenser" and " Permanent split capacitor" are the same.

Comment: Condenser is an old term for capacitor.